# Replace Office 365 with Office Home & Business 2019 for Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-office, office365

When I first bought my MacBook I started using the Office 365 trial from the MacOS App Store. The trial has now expired.

I now have a license for Office Home & Business 2019 for Mac.

Both appear under the "Services & subscriptions" page in my Microsoft Account, with Office 365 Home in the "Cancelled subscriptions" section.

Is it possible to switch the installed Office applications to use the 2019 license, or do I need to uninstall the 365 versions from the App Store and re-install from the downloaded PKG file?

Comment: You will have to reinstall Office since the build your likely using is greater than the build a Office 2019 license grants you.

Comment: I tried installing over the top. App Store has unlinked the apps (they show the cloud icon notifying available to download) but the apps themselves seem to still be linked to 365 - they all have a "Renew Office 365" menu option and Outlook prompts me to renew if I do Send/Receive. I will delete and try again from the installer

Comment: That worked - now marked as Retail License 2019

Comment: @Ramhound make your comment an answer and I'll accept it...

Comment: It even kept all my Outlook account details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to switch the installed Office applications to use the 2019 license, or do I need to uninstall the 365 versions from the App Store and re-install from the downloaded PKG file?

Due to the way Office 365 works, you will receive the current Office build, this build is greater than the Office 2019 build.  You can use an Office 365 license to install Office 2019, all this will do, is allow you to update the Office 2019 to the current Office 365 build.

Since you want to basically downgrade to Office 2019 you will have to reinstall Office in order to achieve your goals.